# how to track a pixel location after rotating image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, data-augmentation

I'm trying to randomly rotate some images with annotations,
I'm trying to understand how to get the new point location after rotation,
my images have different shapes

Example of what I'm trying to do is:  this function to calculate the new position according to this answer ([here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/86402/how-to-get-pixel-location-in-after-rotating-the-image))

```
def new_pixel(x,y,theta,X,Y):
   sin = math.sin(theta)
   cos = math.cos(theta)
   x_new = (x-X/2)*cos + (y-X/2)*sin + X/2
   y_new = -(x-X/2)*sin + (y-Y/2)*cos + Y/2
   return int(x_new),int(y_new)
```

the code of open original image:

```
img = cv2.imread('D://ubun/1.jpg')
print(img.shape)
X, Y, c = img.shape
p1 = (124,291)
p2 = (168,291)
p3 = (169,391)
p4 = (125,391)
img1 = img.copy()
cv2.circle(img1, p1, 10, color=(255,0,0), thickness=2)
plt.imshow(img1)
```

the red dot is the point

[image]

the code for rotation:

```
rotated = ndimage.rotate(img, 45)
print(rotated.shape)
p11 = new_pixel(p1[0],p1[1],45,X,Y)
p22 = new_pixel(p2[0],p2[1],45,X,Y)
p33 = new_pixel(p3[0],p3[1],45,X,Y)
p44 = new_pixel(p4[0],p4[1],45,X,Y)
cv2.circle(rotated, p11, 10, color=(255,0,0), thickness=2)
plt.imshow(rotated)
```

The image after rotation and see the point is not in the correct position after rotation:

[image]

I noticed that image shape is different after rotation, does this effect the calculations ?

Comment: Sorry I can't provide an answer right now, but this is an affine transformation and if you can build up the correct affine transformation matrix, you can use it to send a coordinate into the transformed coordinate system

Comment: The reason is that the output image changes size when rotated relative to the input image.

Comment: Your X/Y size changes during your rotation, but your origin remains the same (top-left). You probably have to multiple the calculated X and Y points by the ratio of the two image side lengths (ration of width for X, height for Y). Just a thought. You are also rotating around the point (width/2, height/2), you may be able to manually compute the new XY point by just doing basic trigonometry.

Comment: thanks, I also think that the image shape after rotating is the problem

Comment: Still unsolved ):

Answer (score 0):

This reply is really late, but even I faced the same issue. So there are basically two issues with your code.

1. math.sin /math.cos takes radians as input not degrees. SO just convert it to radians to get the right result.
2. X,Y : You are taking the height and width of the initial image which was not rotated. This would be right if the resulting image is the same size as the initial image , but since the resulting image resizes the output to fit the complete image after rotation , you need to take X , Y as the new width and height. But you need to consider the new height and width only while your adding it after transformation. SO the formula would be :

x_new = (x-old_Width/2)*cos + (y-old_height/2)*sin + new_width/2

y_new = -(x-old_Width/2)*sin + (y-old_height/2)*cos  + new_height/2

I know this post is too late , but hope this helps out the people whoever faces the same issue.